# Derivative of $c(t)$ in Adiabatic Approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, approximations, adiabatic

In Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics, second edition, $5.6.10$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{c}_m(t)=-\sum_nc_n(t)e^{i[\theta_n(t)-\theta_m(t)]}\langle m;t|\left[\frac\partial{\partial t}|n;t\rangle\right] 
\end{aligned}\tag{5.6.10}$$
where $c_m(t)$ stanstics
$$\begin{aligned}
|\alpha;t\rangle=\sum_nc_n(t)e^{i\theta_n(t)}|n;t\rangle  
\end{aligned}\tag{5.6.5}$$
But use Schrodinger Equation in $5.6.10$, it is
\begin{aligned}
i\hbar\frac\partial{\partial t}|\alpha;t\rangle=H(t)|\alpha;t\rangle 
\end{aligned}
we have
\begin{aligned}
\langle m;t|\left[\frac\partial{\partial t}|n;t\rangle\right] = \frac{1}{i\hbar} \langle m;t|H(t)|n;t\rangle = \frac{1}{i\hbar} E_n(t) \langle m;t|n;t\rangle = \frac{1}{i\hbar} E_n(t) \delta_{mn}
\end{aligned}
But in the book, author don't do this thing. So are there something wrong with me?

Comment: The point is that $H(t)\left|n;t\right>\neq E_n(t)\left|n;t\right>$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent But in 5.6.3, we have this condition.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Instead, it is that $\left<m;t|\frac{\partial\ }{\partial t}|n;t\right>\neq\frac{E_n(t)}{\mathrm i\hslash}\delta_{mn}$ because Equation (5.6.3) implies a different condition.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly assuming that the instantaneous eigenstates $\lvert n; t\rangle$ satisfy the Schrödinger equation. Instead, they are merely defined by the equation
$$H(t)\lvert n;t\rangle = E_n(t)\lvert n;t\rangle.$$

In fact, it is a primary consequence of the adiabatic approximation (which at this point in the derivation in Sakurai has not been made yet) that an instantaneous eigenstate $\lvert n;t\rangle$ satisfies the Schrödinger equation (times dynamic and geometric phase). However, this is *not* generally the case.